# Failure to deploy on netlify: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 255

Tags: deployment, hugo, netlify, blogdown

I failed to deploy my file, which was developed from blogdown (dev, R 3.6.1) and hugo (0.57.2) on the netlify platform.

I have tried to update the URL of my `config.toml` file from `\` to my target web name `https*.com\` . 
Also, I created a `netlify.toml` at the root directory. 
Both of them did not make any sense.

Local development is fine, while the netlify could not be deployed well.

```
failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 255
```

Related code:

```
 blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
```

```
# netlify
[build]
  publish = "public"
  command = "hugo"
[context.production.environment]
  HUGO_VERSION = "0.57.2"
  HUGO_ENV = "production"
  HUGO_ENABLEGITINFO = "true"
[context.branch-deploy.environment]
  HUGO_VERSION = "0.57.2"
```

```
# 0.57.2
blogdown::hugo_version()
```

Comment: From: https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-gotchas/

If you are getting an error 255 when building a Hugo website, try setting HUGO_VERSION to the version you are using locally. This will set the Hugo version that our buildbot uses to build your site.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably too late, but I just had the same issue. It which was solved by the Netlify team.

Trying to deploy through Github provides a built command "hugo". This caused the error message.

Go to your netlify page and the domain settings on the failed deploy. Remove "hugo" in the command built and retry to deploy.